# Want Formated Date and time as 2 mins ago , 1 day ago ,if date> 5days ago then 27 th jan 2017

Tags: apex, formula, object

```
Object :- MBT_SFFB__Conversation__c
Field :- MBT_SFFB__Published_Date__c    Date/Time 
Field :- MBT_SFFB__Published_Date_Formula__c    Formula (Text)
```

Formula :- for MBT_SFFB__Published_Date_Formula__c

```
IF( NOW() - MBT_SFFB__Published_Date__c == 0 ,TEXT( FLOOR( MOD( (NOW() - MBT_SFFB__Published_Date__c ) * 24, 24 ) ) ) & " hours " & TEXT( ROUND( MOD( (NOW() - MBT_SFFB__Published_Date__c ) * 24 * 60, 60 ), 0 ) ) & " minutes",TEXT(DAY(DATEVALUE(MBT_SFFB__Published_Date__c))) +" "+CASE(MONTH(DATEVALUE(MBT_SFFB__Published_Date__c)),1, "Jan",2, "Feb",3, "Mar",4, "Apr",5, "May",6, "Jun",7, "Jul",8, "Aug",9, "Sept",10, "Oct",11,"Nov","Dec") +" "+ TEXT(YEAR(DATEVALUE(MBT_SFFB__Published_Date__c))))
```

Output:- 2 feb 2017 (always Date is populated.)

Example date :- 2 feb 2017.

Want Formatted Date like 5 min ago , 2 days ago , if(datetime > 5 days ago) then it Should come :- 27 th jan 2017

Please Help me to correct my formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible formula is :-

```
IF((NOW() - MBT_SFFB__Published_Date__c) > 0 ,if((NOW() - MBT_SFFB__Published_Date__c) > 5,TEXT(DAY(DATEVALUE(MBT_SFFB__Published_Date__c))) +" "+ CASE(MONTH(DATEVALUE(MBT_SFFB__Published_Date__c)), 1, "Jan", 2, "Feb", 3, Mar", 4, "Apr",5, "May",6, "Jun",7, "Jul", 8, "Aug",9, "Sept", 10, "Oct", 11, "Nov","Dec") +" "+ TEXT(YEAR(DATEVALUE(MBT_SFFB__Published_Date__c))),if((NOW() - MBT_SFFB__Published_Date__c) > 1,TEXT(FLOOR((NOW() - MBT_SFFB__Published_Date__c))) & " days ",TEXT(FLOOR(MOD((NOW() - MBT_SFFB__Published_Date__c) * 24, 24))) & " hours "& TEXT(ROUND(MOD((NOW() - MBT_SFFB__Published_Date__c) * 24 * 60, 60), 0)) &" minutes ago")),"")
```